# Anime about a girl and few other person get chosen by gem power and they can summon some kind of arm weapon

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this movie when I was a kid and I never finished it. It's about a group of students who get chosen by some gem and they have the ability to summon some kind of arm weapon like in *[High School DxD](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2230051/)*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were a kid, so can you tell us what year this was?  Please check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/101407) for anime-id questions, to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: I advise visiting https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1 to view some prompts to help you have more details to [edit] into your question.